# Creating a view in tempdb in SQL Server through a post request

Tags: sql, sql-server

Since I need to send the query statement through a http post request there are certain limitations.
1. It should be a one liner
2. it should be created in tempdb since i am going to drop it afterwards.
since SQL server takes CREATE VIEW statement only in new line I am feeding new line characters to the statement. here is the statement:

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);  ('USE tempdb;' +@NewLineChar + 'GO' +@NewLineChar +'CREATE VIEW temp_view AS select name from sys.databases')
```

This query gives me following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'USE tempdb;'. (Line 1)

what could be the problem ?
Thanks

edit: The same query works like this

```
USE tempdb;
GO 
CREATE VIEW temp_view AS select name from sys.databases
```

where is the syntax error?

Comment: Why not just create a temporary table?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's like you are trying to assign some SQL to a variable, but you don't actually have a variable, you just concatenate some strings with no `SELECT` or `SET`....This seems like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179361). I can't think of a single (good) reason you would need to generate a view on the fly.

Comment: I dont need data I just need to get the schema of the view I make and then I will drop the view too. The statement after "view AS" is coming from user which might be any thing so don't want to create a table that will possibly fill the tempdb

Comment: @GarethD I am working on a Data Visualization app. I give the user the functionality of posting a custom query. I need to get the schema for this query.

Comment: @NewLineChar is for adding new line (\n) in front of CREATE VIEW because that statement has to be in a newline as per sql server documentation

Comment: How exactly are you creating this *schema* you are referring to?

Comment: schema not here, I wanted to give a bigger picture only. my current problem is where is the syntax error in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since SQL server takes CREATE VIEW statement only in new line I am feeding new line characters to the statement.

I have never heard of such a requirement. What the documentation does state is: *The CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch.*

The statement you have in your question doesn't make sense. You can't just drop a `VARCHAR` in SSMS and expect SQL Server to just execute it.

What you probably want is something like the following:

```
USE tempdb;
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'CREATE VIEW temp_view AS SELECT name FROM sys.databases;';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;
```

Or in one line:

```
USE tempdb;DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'CREATE VIEW temp_view AS SELECT name FROM sys.databases;';EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;
```

Comment: Since the statement is coming from Http post request it has to be in one line. I have to declare tempdb in the beginning of the batch because 'CREATE VIEW tempdb.dbo.temp_view...' is not accepted. to make this line first in batch I am using GO statement just before it, and finally I am using CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) to insert LF/CR. my query works when I insert PRINT like this but not the way I want it.`code` DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) PRINT ('USE tempdb;' +@NewLineChar + 'GO' +@NewLineChar +'CREATE VIEW temp_view AS select name from sys.databases')

Comment: @imran I don't know much about HTTP POST requests. I've updated my question to put everything on one line. Maybe that will solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You can create a view in the current database with a name like `_temp_<something>`.  You can even include session information if you want to emulate temporary tables.

Or, create a temporary table with no rows:

```
select top 0 *
into #temp
from <whatever>;
```

You can access the structure of this table.

If you are using a very recent version of SQL Server, use `sp_describe_first_result_set` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)).

Comment: This is fine in some cases but sometimes it will not bring the exact schema from original table. thanks for the help